# iOS simulator are not run the app correctly while changing Devices

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I'm trying to develop an app for iOS 8 , I built the first view of my app. I'm trying to test the first view on all devices  with the iOS simulator the UI works fine but the Code is not run correctly (looks like it compiled some parts from the code not all of it.).

thanks for helping.

Comment: From what I can understand what you're saying is that some parts for your view can't be seen  on all the devices you're trying to test it on. What I recommend you is to look into `Auto Layout` and ` Constrains` which will allow you to display the same view on every device at the same height and width

Answer (score 0):

Might be that it has not compiled an app well. Try to clean it(maybe there is a better way right in xCode, but I do it like I suggest here):
1) go to Home folder: shift+cmd +h
2) Navigate to Library -> Developer -> Xcode -> DerivedData
3) Find folder or folders with your project's name and delete it. You can also delete all from there, if there are projects on which you are not working more. It is kinda temp files of xcode that usually eats up a lot of space.
4) Then try to rebuild your project